# convert string to float in function of cultureinfo

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi I'd like to convert `string` to `float`
I try with `float.Parse`()
the problem the string format is with some user ##,### and with other ##.### it depends on user `CultureInfo`
When I convert string to float I have an error because the float format is with ','
so how to manage that?

Comment: What is the exact code you're using, and a sample float...
This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171202/c-sharp-parsing-float-from-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the example from [Double.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx). Instead of specifying the culture, just ask the system for the current culture.

```
    string userInput = "56,67";
    float output;
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo  info =  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

    if (float.TryParse(userInput, style, info, out output))
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the over load which looks a below

```
float.Parse("20,30", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float,
                          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
```

Or you can use double.parse also as below

```
double.Parse("30.30", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float,
                          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
```